# Netbeans PHP project - can't create a new one

Tags: php, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

netbeans noob - first time running ubuntu and ever using netbeans just a heads up..

I can't create a new project in netbeans. I downloaded the plugins i wanted for PHP

When i go to `File -> New Project` the only item i see under categories is `"Samples."` Samples is broken down into two sub-categories which are `ApiSupport` and `PHP`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: And you're sure you've installed the PHP plugin or the bundle that includes PHP?  Have you tried running with a clean userdir - http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqAlternateUserdir

Comment: I'm sure, I use php at work. It seems the only way is to completely un-install and try again =/ man, i'm already starting to miss windows...

Comment: Weird.  Did you try with a clean userdir?  Also, which download of Netbeans did you install? (where from, version, is it a beta etc)

Comment: I did try clean userdir. Didn't help. The plugin form won't even populate now :S I installed the latest -- netbeans-7.2.1 with everything (java, php etc)... the largest package from the netbeans website

Comment: Since it already is supposed to have PHP it should have just showed up without me downloading the plugin, but nothing showed up at this point

Comment: Which version are you installing? The release one or a dev build?  If you think you've found a genuine bug, please report it to the Netbeans  project (unfortunately you'll have to do battle with Bugzilla to do this :( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is an old thread, but I was looking for the answer today and ran into the same issue. Though the previous answer is technically correct, it was not the issue I was having as I already had the plugin (it came with the Netbeans download). That said, the issue was not having a lamp environment. Once installed apache, php, and mysql, the PHP category showed up.  Instructions from Netbeans can be found on their website, but if you are using Ubuntu (or anything Debian based) you can run

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-mysql mysql
```

PHP5 has a dependency for Apache so it will ask if you want to install dependencies. You just say yes.  If my memory serves, Redhat (CentOS and Fedora) would be:

```
yum install php php-mysql mysql
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have PHP Plugin installed and active.

Click Tools (menu) -> Plugins (menu) -> Installed (tab).

You should see window like this:

[image: PHP Plugin installed and active in NetBeans]

If there is no PHP Plugin - install it (go to Available and search for PHP with description similar to mine).

If there is PHP Plugin but inactive - select it in "Select" table column and press "Activate" button.

If there is PHP Plugin and it is active - reinstall it by using Plugin window.

Comment: Thanks, but this is definitely not the issue. It is installed. Prior to me installing it there were no categories at all :S after i installed it, the samples category showed up. But that's all. I also cannot view plugins now either - it doesn't populate. I suppose the new netbeans has a bug or two...... or three.....

Comment: Anyway - try to reinstall that Plugin. You may also check for plugin updates. Please write what PHP plugin version you are using, i will check what is my version on other computer with Debian.